# error C2227: left of '->yr' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Tags: c++, encryption, visual-studio-2005

I'm writing encrypt/decrypt program for WinCE.

When I compile the program i get errors like:
**error C2227: left of '->yr' must point to class/struct/union/generic type**

The snippet for this is:

```
void ai(struct AES_ctx* ctx, const uint8_t* key)
{
  k(ctx->yr, key);
}
```

and the corresponding header snippet:

```
#define AES_BLOCKLEN 16
#define AES_KEYLEN 32
#define AES_keyExpSize 240

struct AES_ctx
{
  uint8_t yr[AES_keyExpSize];
  uint8_t Iv[AES_BLOCKLEN];
};

void ai(struct AES_ctx* ctx, const uint8_t* key);
```

**With StandardSDK_500 ARMv4I compiler works fine, but with MIPSII I got this.**

Can anybody help to resolve this error?

Comment: Maybe `ai(AES_ctx* ctx` instead?

Comment: I can't get that error to appear with this snippet. Are you sure it's on that line? What's the rest of the error (There should be something like `note: type is 'const uint8_t *'`). This happens when you try to use `->` with a pointer to a non-class type.

Comment: Present a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code: it compiles fine.

(if `ctx` is a macro, defined in some `#included` header file, all sorts of errors could be produced by this code, including the one you report, and this could be compiler dependent; test with `#ifdef ctx ...`)

You may want to run the pre-processor (typically with the option `-E`) and look at the code produced.

(As a side remark, in C++ this looks more like

```
namespace AES {
    constexpr int blocklen=16;
    constexpr int keylen=32;
    constexpr int keyExpSize=240;

    struct ctx {
        std::uint8_t yr[keyExpSize];
        std::uint8_t Iv[blocklen];
    };
    // etc
}
```

i.e. no macros, no pollution of global namespace.)

Comment: Yes with ARM compiler have no problem. MIPSII does this and I don't understand why

Comment: `std::array` please!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this was only minimally 'plussed up' :-)